# Does Erebos lose indestructible when he becomes a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Erebos, God of the Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bErebos%2c%20God%20of%20the%20Dead%5d) is indestructible. Someone tould me that if i have more than five for my devotion that the indestructible comes off. Is that true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Erebos remains indestructible, even as a creature.  Indestructible can apply to any permanents.